# How to handle the sequelize unique constraint error?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to javascript and I need to handle constraint error in sequelize. I searched related to this topic everywhere, but still, I couldn't get a proper workable answer. My attempt it as follows.

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.create(req.body)
        .then(user=> res.json(user));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: "+error);
  }});
```

Here couldn't catch the exception yet. For a valid user input it is able to post the request. So I just need to know a way to handle the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Promise` with `.then().catch()`, or use `async/await` with `try/catch`

This is `Promise`

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.create(req.body)
        .then(user=> res.json(user))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

This is `async/await`

```
app.post('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.body);
      const user = await User.create(req.body);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: "+error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Was looking around for an answer for this, but was not really satisfied with the two given. If you are looking to return a correct response such as a [403](https://developers.rebrandly.com/docs/403-already-exists-errors) this is the solution I have came up with.

```js
app.post('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        var user = await User.create(req.body)
        return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', result: res.json(user) })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
            res.status(403)
            res.send({ status: 'error', message: "User already exists"});
        } else {
            res.status(500)
            res.send({ status: 'error', message: "Something went wrong"});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing two different styles. If you're using `then()`, then the try catch block is unnecessary:

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  User.create(req.body)
    .then(user => res.json(user))
    .catch(error => console.log('Error: ' + error))
})
```

The other style would be using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) package. With async, your code would look like this:

```
app.post('/api/users', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  try {
    const user = await User.create(req.body)
    res.json(user)
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error) }
})
```

Both methods have their advantages and disadvantages that go beyond this snippet and lot of people use both as appropriate, for example the `await` approach works only inside a function declared with `async` like in the second example :`async (req, res)`. In such cases, using `then()` style promise handling is a better approach